# Using HTTP Basic-Auth with Google App Engine URLFetch service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, basic-authentication

How can I specify the username and password for making Basic-Auth requests with App Engine's [URLFetch](http://code.google.com/intl/de/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) service (in Java)?

It seems I can set HTTP headers:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/comment");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("X-MyApp-Version", "2.7.3");
```

What are the appropriate headers for Basic-Auth?

Comment: Is this really an App Engine question, then? Just look up the HTTP RFCs to see how to do basic auth (hint - 'Authorization').

Comment: I was hoping that there might be a convenience wrapper for App Engine similar to Apache HttpClient so that I do not have to set (and base64-encode) the Authorization header manually.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a basic auth header over http:

Authorization: Basic base64 encoded(username:password)

eg:

```
GET /private/index.html HTTP/1.0
Host: myhost.com
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

You will need to do this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/comment");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
"Basic "+codec.encodeBase64String(("username:password").getBytes());
```

And to do that you will want to get a base64 codec api, like the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. And since I put username:password as a property in appengine-web.xml, I just put the encoded version directly in there, so I do not even need a codec. (You can use the openssl commandline: echo -n "username:password" | openssl enc -base64 )

Comment: +1 this also solved a problem I was about to have with HTTP Authentication.  Thanks.  Oh, and getBytes() needs another ) to close setRequestProperty.

Answer (score 14):

For those interested in doing this in Python (as I was), the code looks like this:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch("http://www.example.com/comment",
                        headers={"Authorization": 
                                 "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode("username:pass")})
```

Comment: I believe the code should be as follows:

result = urlfetch.fetch(
    "http://yourserver.com/page/init.php,
    headers = { "Authorization":
                "Basic %s" % base64.encodestring("username:password")[:-1]
});

Comment: Updated to use base64.b64encode. I know it works because it's what I was actually using in my real code.

Answer (score 6):

You set up an Authenticator before you call openConnection() like this,

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
});
```

Since there is only one global default authenticator, this doesn't really work well when you have multiple users doing the URLFetch in multiple threads. I would use Apache HttpClient if that's the case.

EDIT: I was wrong. App Engine doesn't allow Authenticator. Even if it's allowed, we would have the multi-thread issue with a global authenticator instance. Even though you can't create threads, your requests may still get served in different threads. So we just add the header manually using this function,

```
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.util.Base64;
    /**
     * Preemptively set the Authorization header to use Basic Auth.
     * @param connection The HTTP connection
     * @param username Username
     * @param password Password
     */
    public static void setBasicAuth(HttpURLConnection connection,
            String username, String password) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(username);
        buf.append(':');
        buf.append(password);
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            bytes = buf.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            assert false;
        }

        String header = "Basic " + Base64.encode(bytes);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", header);
    }
```

Comment: There is only a single thread on App Engine ... (by the way, is there any documentation that this is guaranteed to be the case?)

Comment: We had some problem with this, I thought it was threading. I will check with the person who implemented this when I get back to office next week.

Comment: Just talked with the guy who ported our app to Google. See my edits.

Answer (score 4):

Using `HttpURLConnection` gave me some problems (for some reason the server I was trying to connect to didn't accept auth credentials), and finally I realized that it's actually much easier to do using GAE's low-level URLFetch API (`com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch`) like so:

```
URL fetchurl = new URL(url);

String nameAndPassword = credentials.get("name")+":"+credentials.get("password");
String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encode(nameAndPassword.getBytes());

HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(fetchurl);
request.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Authorization", authorizationString));

HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
System.out.println(new String(response.getContent()));
```

This worked.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, you can also set the timeout: FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withDeadline(10);  HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest( fetchurl, HTTPMethod.GET, fetchOptions);

Answer (score 3):

There is a wrapper on Apache HttpClient for App Engine

please go through the post http://esxx.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html

http://peterkenji.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-apache-httpclient-4-with-google.html

Answer (score 1):

Note on the first answer: setRequestProperty should get the property name without the colon ("Authorization" rather than "Authorization:").