# setDefaultAuthenticator causes a java.security.AccessControlException in GWT web application

Tags: java, exception, gwt, httprequest, policy

I am creating a web application using GWT, the server provides a service to the client. In this service, it must generate an HTTP request to another server with authentication. The following code describes how to make the request:

```
public int request()
{
    Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(username, password));
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_string);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(buildRequest());
        wr.flush();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        //the rest is to handle the response ...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

`MyAuthenticator` is implemented as suggested [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Auth.html), I tested the code and it works like a charm, but when I try to incorporate it in GWT project, I am getting an exception:

```
//huge stack trace above ... what is important is the following
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.NetPermission setDefaultAuthenticator)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently GAE does *not* allow Authenticator, this is why I got this exception, a similar problem found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1341081/337194), the solution is to add the Authentication header manually as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341081/using-http-basic-auth-with-google-app-engine-urlfetch-service/1352698#1352698).

Answer (score 0):

I can see two situations:

1. You are using AppEngine to run it. I believe it won't work.
2. You are using it on GWT's client side. Move it to server side.

Comment: Actually I am running this code server side. However, I read something about writing permission grants but I do not know if it is possible to do with GAE.