# Python GAE urlfetch credentials

Tags: python, google-app-engine, credentials, urlfetch

I'd like to know if the Google App Engine [URL Fetch Python API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) does not support accessing URLs that have credentials:

```
http://username:password@www.domain.com/
```

It should be a basic feature, but I cannot get it to work and could not find any documentation about it being supported or not as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268060/110707 (the question is about Java, but this answer addresses Python)

Comment: you've nailed it @Wooble, thanks!

Comment: @raugfer : Post your solution as an Answer

Comment: @GautamK: Just did it, sorry, I'm a newbie here :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SOLUTION - here's how it should be done:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch("http://www.domain.com/",
                        headers={"Authorization": 
                                 "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode("username:password")})
```